# Securely access route with JWT and localstorage

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, ejs

I'm building a small application where a user logs in and gets redirected to /profile. Right now, I fetch the JWT from localstorage and check it via the server. The server then sends it back to the client to tell me if it's a valid session or not.

jQuery/Client:

```
  UserController.initPanel = () => {
    if (session === null) {
     window.location = "/";
    } else {
      UserController.requestAuth(session);
    }
  };

  UserController.requestAuth = (sessionToken) => {
    var settings = {
      "url": "/api/auth", 
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${sessionToken}`,
      },
      "data": ""
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  };
```

Node.js/auth.js route:

```
router.post("/",  (req, res) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (typeof authHeader !== 'undefined') {
        const bearerToken = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
        verifyToken(bearerToken, (authData) => {
            tokenRequest(authData, (authResponse) => {
                handleAuthResponse(req, res, authResponse);
            })
        });
    }
});

const handleAuthResponse = (req, res, authResponse) => {
    console.log(authResponse);
    return res.status(200).json(authResponse);
}


const verifyToken = (token, cb) => {
    jwt.verify(token, 'mysecret', (err, authData) => {
    if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(403)
    } else {
        cb(authData);
    }
    });
}

const tokenRequest = (authHeader, cb) => {
    //console.log(authHeader);
    var config = {
        headers: {'Authorization': `bearer ${authHeader.token}`}
    };
    axios.get('https://myapi.dev/api/session/me', config)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.data.error) {
        return response.data
      } else {
        cb(res.data);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error', error);
    }); 

}
```

I feel like this isn't the correct way to do it. I'm rendering templates with ejs:

```
router.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  const settings = {
    title: "Profile",
    revslider: false
  };
  res.render("profile/profile", { settings: settings } );
});
```

And if for some reason, JS is disabled, /profile is still accessible. Which isn't that big of a problem, it just feels wrong.

So, is it possible to access /profile route, securely checking for authorization server-side first, before rendering?

Also, auth.js returns some user data I could use in the .ejs template. So that's another reason I'd like to try check auth before rendering as well.

EDIT:

Auth middleware, which I didn't use because I wasn't sure how to pass in the token?

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(req.body.token, 'mysecret');
        req.token = decoded;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Auth Failed'
        }); 
    }
    next();
}
```

Comment: What about using middleware within express (assuming that's what you're using) and apply that to all routes you want to protect.

Comment: I had auth as middleware, but I wasn't sure as how to pass the session token to that.

Comment: The session token would be part of the req, which is always passed to middleware :) would you like me to write a basic example as an answer?

Comment: Yes please @steadweb

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you Jess. Are you using the following package to handle sessions? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Answer (score 0):

Very basic `middleware` implementation below which leverages `express` and `express-session`.

We basically create a simple function to check `req.session` exists, within that object, you could have something that identifies whether the user has actually authenticated. I'd recommend you add your own logic here to further check the user status.

```
const authCheckMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  // Perform auth checking logic here, which you can attach
  // to any route.
  if(!req.session) {
      return res.redirect('/');
  }

  next();
};
```

The `authCheckMiddleware` can be attached to any `route`, with `app.use` or `router.use`. The `req` object is passed to all middleware.

```
// Use the authCheckMiddleware function
router.use('/profile', authCheckMiddleware);
```

Your `router.get('/profile')` call is now protected by the above middleware.

```
// Route protected by above auth check middleware
router.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  const settings = {
      title: "Profile",
      revslider: false
  };

  res.render("profile/profile", { settings: settings } );
});
```

Comment: Where does the "session" check if the session is stored via localstorage?

Comment: That's frontend, I'm concentrating on backend. So before you hit the frontend, this should kick in and redirect you to the login route. If you have frontend routes only, with XHR (AJAX) you'll need to return a 401 status and do the same.